# How to Change Search Text that Google shows for my Joomla Site

Tags: joomla, meta

Hi I have built a joomla search that has been live for a couple of months and is working completely fine. One of the things that I came across last week is when i search in Google for 'MyCompany' then this brings up the link for my site, but underneath the link rather than a brief text about the company all i see is the banner image names that have been used on the site.

Unfortunately I have never really dwelled into the SEO side of the website but would really like to know what I need to do on the site to get this fixed, would really appreciate it if somebody could please advise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16219413

Comment: Thanks Neil for that...